# Alamofire return empty response in Mac os command line app

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I wonder why my code not working. I create url and try to get response with Alamofire. Url is correct, it provide data in Postman.

Code is:

```
static func getRepolist(request: URLRequest?,
                            completion: ([String]) -> ()) {
        guard let request = request else { return }

        Alamofire.request(request)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
        }
    }
```

Request is (taked it from `po request` in console):

```
▿ https://api.github.com/search/users?q=srdanrasic
  ▿ url : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://api.github.com/search/users?q=srdanrasic
  - cachePolicy : 0
  - timeoutInterval : 60.0
  - mainDocumentURL : nil
  - networkServiceType : __ObjC.NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType
  - allowsCellularAccess : true
  ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
    - some : "GET"
  ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
    - some : 0 elements
  - httpBody : nil
  - httpBodyStream : nil
  - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
  - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Why it does not print anything? It's not get in completion block.
It just tell me in log - Program ended with exit code: 0. 
Maybe there is no time for request to complete before app finish running?

Comment: What was your response code? 200 ?

Comment: @KeghamK. i suppose so, because Alamofire validate() perform status code check.

Comment: Try to print out `response.result.value` is it empty?

Answer (score 1):

You should call completion youself after getting correct data and parsing it

```
 Alamofire.request(request)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        completion(response["Key"]) // assume response["Key"] = [String]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way... Because the data you are receiving in the body is most probably json data so return as `Any`

```
static func getRepolist(request: URLRequest?,
                        completion: ([Any]) -> ()) {
    guard let request = request else { return }

    Alamofire.request(request)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
      case.success( _):
         print(response.result.value)
         let body:Any = response.result.value
         completion(body)
       case.failure( _):
         let errData = response.data
         print(String(data: errData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "NO ERROR DATA")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in fact, i used command line tool. So program terminate before i get data. Was solving easily by adding:

```
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15))
```

Comment: Rather than for a fixed 15 seconds, use a `while` loop checking some state property. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1412430-run) shows an Objective-C example of `run(mode:before:)`, but the Swift pattern would be similar.